# Where can I find Dogmeat after dismissing him to Sanctuary Hills?

Tags: fallout-4

I recently dismissed Dogmeat in favor of Codsworth, and I'm fairly sure I sent him to Sanctuary Hills. However, I've had a fairly detailed look around the place and I haven't found him yet. Does anyone know where he is?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

He can spawn back at gas station where you first found him, or at one of the dog houses in Sanctuary.

If you scrapped the dog house that was there, I would go look at the gas station you first found him at.

---

Also, if you cannot find him at all, use the following (on PC):

1. Open the Console by pressing <kbd>`</kbd> (same as <kbd>~</kbd> on US keyboards)
2. Type: `player.moveto 1d162`
3. Press: <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This will teleport you to Dogmeat's location, allowing you to retrieve him and move the doghouse he went to.

Comment: FYI there are multiple dog houses in sanctuary.  I had to find and scrap all but one to force him to a specific location

Comment: They also kind of wander around the settlement, I don't think he will always be in a dog house.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The console didn't show any errors, but neither did Dogmeat appear.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jared You may need to try again, as aman207 added another 0 to the console command for me.

Comment: I've had more luck finding Dogmeat at his doghouse(s) at night. If you can't find him, sleep or wait until night time and check the doghouse.

Comment: How many dog houses are in Sanctuary?

Comment: @Ayelis 2 that I know of. One to the East of your house, and one at your house.

Comment: There are two. We was in one of them for me!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the commands `prid 1d162` and `moveto player` to teleport Dogmeat to you.

Answer (score 5):

If the dog still doesn't appear, make sure it isn't on the roof. If it is, build stairs to the roof.

Comment: This is a problem not just with Dogmeat, but other settlers too. They seem to spawn on top of your old house. This is a good general solution for not just dogmeat, but for the rest of them to find their way off the roof.

Answer (score 3):

You can normally find him at the Red Rocket Gas Station or in a Dog House at Sanctuary. But the dog house is located behind the yellow house with dog bowls in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have another companion you have to dismiss them before he spawns at red rocket where you found him first of all

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to get DogMeat to reappear until a Main Story quest where he is used. I had searched all of Sanctuary and Red Rocket.

Sidenote: It's funny (Kereng) you mention looking on the roof. I returned from a mission to begin sorting my 'junk' and I kept hearing the sound of the Brahmin like it was inside the house. Turns out, it was on the roof.

Comment: I've had a Brahmin spawn inside the house before. They're so meta...

Comment: Trashcan Carla's Brahmin with the packs on it spawned inside my house, and I can't get him to leave. I may end up moving him via console, but for now I'll just wait.