# Where did Dogmeat go?

Tags: fallout-4

[image] [image]

I completed Unlikely Valintine and invited Valintine to join me.  Than I did Reunion and followed DogMeat.  Once I got to Fort Hagen Valintine said something along the lines of "You should give DogMeat a rest, he's done enough".

I haven't seen DogMeat since.  Where did he go?  I looked around Sanctuary Hills and didn't see him.

---

**Update:** I didn't explicitly assign DogMeat to any of my settlements, he just left.  But I'll check the Gas Station (as recommended in [Where can I find Dogmeat after dismissing him to Sanctuary Hills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242995/where-can-i-find-dogmeat-after-dismissing-him-to-sanctuary-hills)) and report back.

Comment: @Ben Possibly, but this question seems to be inquiring more after the mechanic behind Dogmeat's departure than after how to find him. At least that is my initial reading.

Comment: While that is the case @Nick the answer of the other question will answer this one.. Dogmeat has left and he will either appear at a dog house in Sanctuary or go back to the Red Rocket coolant station and such (which is where he goes after the above event.. All other times it asks you where to send him, this is just the one event that doesnt).

Comment: I just did this mission last night. Dogmeat went back to Red Rocket station next to sanctuary instead of back to Sanctuary Hills where I had him assigned.

Comment: I just found Dogmeat. I was cleaning houses of unwanted crap and there he was in a dog-house. I love that dog.